# Why is $Rad(P_S)/Soc(P_S)$ a direct sum of two uniserial modules?

Tags: group-theory, modules, representation-theory

Why is $Rad(P_S)/Soc(P_S)$ a direct sum of two uniserial modules? Where $P$ is the projective cover of some simple $kG$-module $S$. (We may assume char$(k)$|$|G|$.)

This is taken from Page 119 of Alperin's Local Rep Theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn’t true for general $G$ and $S$, and neither does Alperin claim it is. In the reference you give, this is part of the *definition* of a Brauer tree algebra. The main result of the rest of the chapter is that block algebras with cyclic defect group are Brauer tree algebras, but block algebras with non-cyclic defect group are not.